# WMIC in Windows Bash

Tags: windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I try to use WMIC in Windows Bash, it says command not found. Though, in git-bash and Cygwin I am able to use WMIC, so how can I achieve this in Windows Bash?

Comment: You cannot.  The environment is separate, it literally is an Ubuntu installation, Cygwin and git-bash are not.

Comment: @ramhound is there something similar to wmic for Ubuntu? Or how could I get lua working with Cygwin or Git-Bash? As the two say Lua: command not found, but cmd works fine with lua. But I need Git-bash or Cygwin for the character escaping. I'm trying to run cmdfetch by hal ullr on github.

Comment: The proper tag for this is windows-linux-subsystem. Other SO sites use also tag "wsl".

Comment: Maybe consider asking a question that matches your particular use case? As WMIC stands for "Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line" it's unlikely there is a direct translation but there probably is some kind of option available. It would depend on what your goal is. To get `Lua` working you could just install it on Windows instead of the subsystem. The github page for that script has information on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try `wmic.exe` the .exe is important.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent WSL update, it become possible to run Windows commands from within the "bash box". For details, see: [Invoking Windows binaries from WSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/interop)

Note that this ability can be turned off via a magic /proc/sys file.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will launch wmic.exe from windows 10 bash shell:

```
bash -c "wmic.exe"
```